"A breakpoint instruction (__debugbreak() statement or a similar call) was executed" without breakpoint :(
Member.h
pragma once

#ifndef MEMBER_H
#define MEMBER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Member {
private:
    char* m_id;
    char* m_pwd;
    char* m_name;
    int m_age;
public:
    Member();
    Member(const char* id, const char* pwd, const char* name, int age);

    char* getID();
    char* getPWD();
    char* getName();
    int getAge();

    void setID(char* id);
    void setPWD(char* pwd);
    void setName(char* name);
    void setAge(int age);

    void printMeminfo();
    ~Member();
};

#endif

Member.cpp
#include "Member.h"

Member::Member() {
    char* m_id = new char;
    char* m_pwd = new char;
    char* m_name = new char;
    int m_age = 0;
}; 

Member::Member(const char* id, const char* pwd, const char* name, int age) {
    int len = strlen(id);
    char* m_id = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_id, len + 1, id);
    len = strlen(pwd);
    char* m_pwd = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_pwd, len + 1, pwd);
    len = strlen(name);
    char* m_name = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_name, len + 1, name);
    int m_age = age;
}; 

char* Member::getID() { return m_id; }
char* Member::getPWD() { return m_pwd; }
char* Member::getName() { return m_name; }
int Member::getAge() { return m_age; }

void Member::setID(char* id) { 
    m_id = id;
}
void Member::setPWD(char* pwd) {
    m_pwd = pwd;
}
void Member::setName(char* name) {
    m_name = name;
}
void Member::setAge(int age) { m_age = age; }

void Member::printMeminfo() {
    cout << m_id << ' ' << m_name << ' ' << m_age << endl;
}
Member::~Member() {
    delete[] m_id;
    delete[] m_pwd;
    delete[] m_name;
}

main.cpp
#include "Member.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Member* mem = new Member[4] {
        Member(), Member(), Member(), Member()
    };
    char infos[4][3][11]{
        {"cheol88", "cheol88", "김철수"}, {"ywjeong123", "12345^", "정연우"},
        {"Jiwoon456", "34563%", "박지운"}, {"Choi931", "96454$$", "최지우"}
    };
    int ages[4] = { 23, 31, 35, 26 };
    for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
        mem[a].setID(infos[a][0]);
        mem[a].setPWD(infos[a][1]);
        mem[a].setName(infos[a][2]);
        mem[a].setAge(ages[a]);
    }
    
    char* ID = new char;
    char* PW = new char;
    while (1) {
        cout << "ID looking for : ";
        cin >> ID;
        cout << "Password of the ID : ";
        cin >> PW;
        int found = 0;
        if ((strcmp(ID, "0000")==0) && (strcmp(PW, "0000")==0)) {
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if ((strcmp(ID, mem[i].getID())==0) && (strcmp(PW, mem[i].getPWD())==0)) {
                mem[0].printMeminfo();
                found = 1;
            }
        }
        if (found == 0) {
            cout << "Not found" << endl;
        }
    }
    delete[] mem;
    delete ID;
    delete PW;
    return 0;
}

The error I get:
HEAP[Project3.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 000001CB11980000, 00000065390FF843 )
A breakpoint instruction (__debugbreak() statement or a similar call) was executed in Project3.exe.
Please enlighten me I really have no idea
Kept had a research and I guess the problem is related with 'delete'..
but that's all..

The error you are noticing is probably indeed because of a delete statement. In your main() function you assign the address of a char[], which has automatic storage duration (it lives on the stack), to a pointer which is a member of Member. In the destructor Member::~Member() you call delete[] on this pointer. Calling delete on a pointer that was not obtained via new is undefined behavior (UB) by the C++ standard. You have the same problem with m_id, m_pwd and m_name.
mem[a].setID(infos[a][0]);

void Member::setID(char* id) { 
    m_id = id;
}

Member::~Member() {
    delete[] m_id;
    delete[] m_pwd;
    delete[] m_name;
}

To avoid all those headaches when using pointers you should just use std::string which handles all the necessary memory management instead of plain C-style char*. And for dynamic arrays you should use std::vector instead of again the C-style Member*. In your case you don't really need to dynamically allocate your array mem and a std::array would suffice.

You only noticed the above described problem. It is not a syntax error or something similar which the compiler could check for. It is UB and the compiler assumes that you now what you are doing and UB will not appear. When you have UB in your code, everything can happen. It can cause a debug-break which it did in this case or it can just crash or do something else entirely. Even worse than that is when it works like you would expect and only when you ship your code to a client it suddenly behaves in a different way.
An example for this is in your code as well:
char* ID = new char;
cin >> ID;

ID only points to a single char. This could only store the NUL-terminator \0 for a string, but you try to read a whole string. What happens if you type cheol88 into your terminal? That's more than you can store and you access memory which isn't yours. You got rather unlucky and it worked for you.
When I ran your code on my machine it crashed on reading the input. I had a tool (AdressSanitizer) enabled which checks for such errors. And there are many other errors in your code you should change.
When I compile your code with warnings enabled I get 28 warnings. All of those could potentially be errors. You should learn to understand compiler warnings and errors and treat them as errors. You can do that in Visual Studio when you right-click your project, select Properties, then C/C++, go to Warning Level and select /W4 and below that enable Treat Warnings As Errors.
